# Using clip-path property affects a card flip animation in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to use the clip path property to make an effect to the container of a card in Safari. This card has a flip animation to show information in both sides of it. However when I use this property the information is not shown, but the html elements are there. Have you faced something similar?

Expected:

[image]

Reality:

[image]